# Wired network not connecting automatically after xubuntu 14.10 upgrade

Tags: networking, upgrade, xubuntu, 14.10

Last weekend I upgraded my 14.04 xubuntu to the latest release, 14.10 (out of curiosity). Ever since every time I login I have to manually select the wired connection to connect to. The first notification that I see after the login is saying something like "Network disconnected - You are now offline".

I searched for a solution to this matter but I couldn't find anything to fit and fix my problem.

If needed:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<mac:address>,

[ifupdown]
managed=true # this was false but I changed it to true yesterday, thinking it will solve the issue
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: @int_ua not the same issue

Comment: that guy's problem (from what I read) was that he has wired connection but no internet and no network. my problem was that on each login the network got disconnected by itself, but it worked if I chose the connection from the menu. my problem was that it didn't connect automatically on login, but putting me offline. two different problems.

Comment: yes, really. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. What I did to solve the problem: First I reverted the content of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` to the original content:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<mac:address>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And the thing that actually solved the issue was to tick the checkbox from the wired connection properties titled `All users may connect to this network` (which is strange because I haven't modified any of the settings before or after the upgrade):

[image]

After this last step everything worked as before.

If not try:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Not working ! This not real answer if a user lost `network-manager` service.  So need a connection for fix/rebuild. Don't waste user's time ! Try @josh answer before fixing a service !

Answer (score 3):

Although all responders mean well, I have not ever seen such a long collection of clueless, useless answers based solely on hocus-pocus and random knee-jerk file editing and click-on-options. I am afraid, and always in my opinion, you approach Linux using a head-down-legs-up approach. Totally upside-down.

Network manager has an **autoconnect setting** for each connection. As simple and as reasonable and as one would expect from reasonable and logical Linux human developers who possess, still, the quality of common-sense.

An **autoconnect setting**?, you must be kidding! Wow! "*I thought all was black magic and praying and fingers-crossing like in the computer games I play all day long burning my brain cells with.*"

Anyway, back to business, I hope this helps someone:

Using the command line interface of Network manager one can enable or disable this option like so:

`nmcli connection modify <connection-name> connection.autoconnect yes`

where `<connection-name>` should be the name of the connectiopn, often just `eth0`.

P.s. you can list all your connections by name using:

`nmcli connection show`

or, more traditionally,

`ifconfig -a`

In order to view all options for a connection do:

`nmcli connection show <connection-name>`

(again, `<connection-name>` is the name of the connection, something like `eth0`)

What's more, you do not need to be root to do any of the above.

Comment: I guess it's because nmcli is relatively new?  Anyway vote for this one!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

change managed=false to managed=true.

From the top-right corner select Edit Connections, and add a new connection. Specify your ip address, netmask, gateway, and the DNS server being 8.8.8.8.

Then add these two lines to /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Then run:

sudo service network-manager restart.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `managed` is already set to `true` but it doesn't solve the issue. what I've found out now is that if I restart manually the network-manager the wired network connection gets established. this is very strange.

Comment: I had this exact issue after a sever upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 and a simple change from managed=false to true, and a restart of the network-manager resolved it for me.

Comment: Also had this issue on upgrade to xubuntu 18.04. Changing 'managed=true' in NetworkManager.conf resolved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my first Answare I deleted it because it wass not related to the topic.

But I have to say the same. All you need to do is to configure /network/interfaces with the propper details.

Something like

auto eth0
eth0 inet dhcp

should work if yiu use a dhcp capable router

if not you have to define a static Ip adress and your gateway. You can also define proper name servers.

If you Edit your Answare with valuse like

```
ip address 
netmask 
network 
gateway
broadcast
```

We should be able to figure out something for you

Network Manager is crappy and will not work every time
Also it's documentation lacks.

Please use network/interfaces to make ubuntu able to use if up and ifdown as well es ifconfig.

Comment: I added `auth eth0 inet dhcp` to `/etc/network/interfaces` and now when I login the network gets connected, but to a new connection which was created automatically, it doesn't select my existing connection http://i.imgur.com/q6TaVph.png. is there a way I could do so it will select my existing connection ? oh, and in the network connections list this new connection cannot be neither edited or deleted.

Comment: This is because of the DHCP service that ships with your router. If you need a static up address you can configure this as well by using     in et static

Comment: I figured it out. Check my answer to see what was the issue. Though, I will give you the bounty since it will be lost if I don't select an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem, and you could try from the terminal enter this:

```
rfkill list
```

and you see if there is a soft block or hardblock, and if there is type in the terminal:

```
rfkill nosoftblock
```

or
    rfkill nohardblock

and then type in this in the terminal:

```
lslist
```

you can see if network is down or up if it is type in the terminal:

```
lslist ifup
```

or

```
lslist ifdown
```

and then type in the terminal this:

```
lsmod wlan0
lsusb -s wlan0
```

and connect to the network and but on log on at startup, and then type in the terminal this:

```
nmap -v -iR 10000 -Pn -p (port)
firefox
```

and then it should probaly work fine this way.